# Adding number of days to dates Java

Tags: java, date

```
Date initialDate= Date.valueOf("2010-08-17");
System.out.println("Initial date:" + initialDate);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(initialDate);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 15);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println("Output: " + output);
```

The results obtained were

Initial date:2010-08-17

Output: 2010-00-01

The problem is the month does not increment.

Comment: Firstly, I'd strongly recommend *not* using `Date.valueOf` - and ideally not using `Date`/`Calendar` at all, but using Joda Time or Java 8's `java.time` classes if at all possible. (Note that it's only `java.sql.Date` that even *has* `Date.valueOf`...)

Comment: Where did you see the `valueOf` method in `Date` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern for month is `MM` not `mm`.